# Keycloak - Where are the authServerUrl and authUrl stored?

Tags: keycloak

I have set up Keycloak locally successfully (localhost). However, since I was using ngrok I changed authServerUrl and authUrl in the Admin console (realm settings) to the ngrok URL. The ngrok URL has now changed and I cannot access the Keycloak admin console because it's trying the open the old ngrok URL for the Admin page.

Is there a folder, xml or json file where I can adjust the authServerUrl and authUrl for Keycloak locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to edit/correct the `authServerUrl` and `authUrl` via CLI. The property is called `frontendUrl` in the realm JSON file.

In case anyone comes across the same here is the command:

`./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s attributes.frontendUrl=http://localhost:8080/auth`